# Magento percentage off basket total

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

Is it possible to have a shopping cart rule that gives the user 25% off the whole total of the basket without using a coupon? It needs to be the total price and not 25% off each product.

Our site is running Magento 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using **Promotions > Shopping Cart Price rules** you just set it to take 25% off the basket total, and set it to 'No Coupon'.

Shopping cart price rules are rules that effect the total of the cart, not the products individually. Catalog price rules are for individual product discounts.